# Listwrapper not allowing multiplication of learning rate and thus no update of weight for Nueral Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am new to tensorflow  and nueral networks. I am trying to create a NN to estimate y = x^2

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x_train = tf.constant(value = np.linspace(-10,10,50),dtype='float32')
x_train = tf.reshape(x_train,shape=[50,1])
y_train = x_train**2
layers = [1,3,4,1]
```

I created a nueral network class to obtain my weights and biases and run forward propagation.

```
class NN(tf.Module):
        def __init__(self,layers,name=None):
            super().__init__(name=name)
            self.layers = layers
    
            self.weights, self.biases = self.initialze(layers)
            
        def initialze(self,layers) :
            num_layers = len(layers)
            weights = []
            biases = []
            for i in range(num_layers-1):
                in_dim = layers[i]
                out_dim = layers[i+1]
                stddev = np.sqrt(2/(in_dim + out_dim))
                b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,layers[i+1]], dtype='float32'), dtype='float32')
                W =  tf.Variable(tf.random.truncated_normal([in_dim, out_dim], stddev=stddev), dtype='float32')
                weights.append(W)
                biases.append(b)
            return weights, biases
        def __call__(self,x):
            Z = x
            num_layers = len(self.layers)
            for i in range(num_layers-1):
                Z =tf.math.add(tf.linalg.matmul(Z ,self.weights[i]),self.biases[i])
            return Z
            
                
    My_NN = NN(layers)
```

Next I created a class updat to do backward propogation

```
class updat:
    def __init__(self,y_train,x_train):
        
        self.y_train =  y_train
        self.x_train = x_train
        self.l_r = 0.1
    def get_grad(self,My_NN):
            with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
                tape.watch(My_NN.weights)
                tape.watch(My_NN.biases)
                loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.y_train-My_NN(self.x_train)))
                
            dw,db = tape.gradient(loss, [My_NN.weights,My_NN.biases])
            print(dw,'weight')
            print(db,'biases')
            My_NN.weights -= (self.l_r * dw)
            My_NN.biases -=(self.l_r * db)
            
            del tape

            return loss
    def report(self, loss):
        return f"W = {My_NN.weights.numpy():1.2f}, b = {My_NN.biases.numpy():1.2f}, loss={loss:2.5f}"
   

        
    def prop(self,epochs,My_NN):
        for epoch in epochs:
            loss = self.get_grad(My_NN)
            
            current_loss = loss
           
            print(f"Epoch {epoch:2d}:")
            print("    ", report(current_loss,My_NN))
```

But when I run the code

```
model = updat(y_train,x_train)
epochs = range(10)
model.prop(epochs,My_NN)
```

I get an error saying

> My_NN.weights -= (self.l_r * dw)

> My_NN.biases -=(self.l_r * db)

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

I tried substituting `My_NN.weights -= (lr*dw)`
with `My_NN.weights.assign_sub(lr*dw)`
still it shows that

> 'ListWrapper' object has no attribute 'assign_sub'

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you could use keras like here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/404410

Answer (score 0):

TURN

```py
My_NN.weights -= (self.l_r * dw)
My_NN.biases -=(self.l_r * db)
```

TO

```py
for weight,d_weight in zip(My_NN.weights,dw):
    weight.assign_sub(self.l_r * d_weight) 
for bias,d_bias in zip(My_NN.biases,db):
    bias.assign_sub(self.l_r * d_bias)
```

can solve the problem.

Because `My_NN.weights` is a list of `tf.Variable`'s `ref` and `dw` is corresponding list of `tf.constant`. We cannot modify it outside the list unless we iterate over the list. Additionally, if we want to update `tf.Variable`, we should use its `assign` .etc methods, this is like modifying the content specified by the pointer variable in C language.

More conveniently, we usually use `tf.keras.optimizers`'s `apply_gridents()`, even `minimize()` to updata varibales directly.

For this specific task and your more `process oriented` coding approach, here I give out some suggestions for stable training:

1. add `activations` to constrain the fitting ability of this model:

```
def __call__(self,x):
    Z = x
    num_layers = len(self.layers)
    for i in range(num_layers-2):
        y = tf.math.add(tf.linalg.matmul(Z ,self.weights[i]),self.biases[i])
        Z = tf.nn.relu(y)
    i+=1
    return tf.math.add(tf.linalg.matmul(Z ,self.weights[i]),self.biases[i])
```

2. make lower `learning_rate`:

```
self.l_r = 0.001 # self.l_r = 0.1
```

3. do more `epochs`:

```
epochs = range(1000) # epochs = range(10)
```

Since initial value of trainable wights will also influence the training stability, you may need to re-train several times. In my
tests, the above modification works.

Comment: Thank you so much. It did work, but the error is very high like 2000's. Do you know why is it so.

Comment: @NBN  The most problem is that there is no activation in each layer, which lead to the network can only fit linear functions. However, the data is y=x**2, so can not get effective regression. Additionally, you should make a lower `learning_rate`, more `epochs`. I have added some additional suggestion codes in above answer for your training task.

Comment: Thank you so much. So overall the idea is correct and there is some problem because of the function I chose.